# Dynamically add data to MatTableDataSource Material Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to dynamically add data to a `MatTableDataSource`

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

```
dataSource1 =  new  MatTableDataSource ();

      addRiesgo(model: any) {
        const test: Riesgo = { descripcion: model.descripcionIdentificacion, riesgoinherente: '', riesgoresidual: '' };
      this.dataSource1.data.push(test);

      }
```

This doesn't work for me , not update

Comment: no update............

Comment: Can you show all code? where you call `addRiego()` on template or TS

Answer (score 0):

Somehow direct update to this.dataSource.data will not work. You can try like this.

```
const data = this.dataSource.data;
data.push(test);
this.dataSource.data = data;
```

Here is the working demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qfheuu

Hope this helps.